# Obtaining input value on Button Click to send as query to the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have a Custom TextField n Button Component which serves as a Child component to SearchModal Component which inturn is the Child of Main Component , As per Below Code , Upon clicking Button i want to fetch the value present in the text field and pass it to the redux method , But i am not able to so since textfield is another component in SearchModal .

```
App.js

this.state={
  queryValue:''
}

onSearch = event => {
     let appliedFilters = this.getAppliedFilters(); //functoin to obtain filters
     this.setState({ queryValue: event.target.value }) /* need to fetch the input value here */
    console.log(this.state.queryValue)
    };

<SearchModal
   onSubmit={this.onSearch}
 />
```

Search Modal Has Textfield and Button Component with respective OnChange and OnClick(which is onSubmit received as props)  Handlers.

SearchModal.js

```
this.state={
   query:''
}

onChange = e => this.setState({ query: e.target.value });
onSubmit = () => this.props.onSubmit(this.state.query);

<TextField
    ref={textField => (this.textField =textField)}
    id="search-modal-input"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
    search
 />

<Button
    onClick={this.onSubmit}
    variant="nav-link-button"
    fullWidth
  />
```

as you can see above already onCHange is being targeted in TextField method , but i want to perform the same in app.js file also

Comment: Please provide more details or code snippet

Comment: We do need to see some code, but it sounds like you'll ultimately want to have a data property in `SearchModal` that is bound to the textbox value.

Comment: Have updated , check now